# Counting the null columns in a row

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am interested in counting the `null` columns in a single row in Django.

Example:

```
model: Student
fields: fname,lname, father_name
Student("max",null,null)
```

return `lname` and `father_name`, or `2`.

Answer (score 3):

[`Student._meta.get_fields()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields) will give you the list of all fields, so you can do:

```py
fields = Student._meta.get_fields()
null_fields = [f.name for f in fields if getattr(my_student, f.name) is None]

print(null_fields)       # should print ['lname', 'father_name']
print(len(null_fields))  # should print 2
```

Comment: All good. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it if it helped.